# Customize Self-Service Portal

Tags: visualforce, portal

I'm wondering if others try (and succedded) to customize the Self-Service portal with Visualforce components and apex. There are parts that can be customized by standard page layout, and some parts  that can't be customized (Home, Find Solutions section).
I got a response from SF support saying it's possible to change the pages via visualforce, my real concern is the "Related Cases" column on the "find solution" section (these are cases of all SSP Users, not just the logged in user).

There are several more things i'd like to customize, just checking if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customise the self-service portal in this way I'm afraid - this is in keeping with it being a free license.  I suspect that support have confused this with the Service Cloud Portal, which is the high volume customer portal.